# How to configure Azure AAD Connect to synch with OpenLDAP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openldap

I am trying to set up AAD Connect to synchronise our in-house LDAP user directory with the Azure AAD.  Documentation says to use AAD Connect, and that while Microsoft would (of course) prefer you have Active Directory locally to link to, it should also work with an SQL or LDAP backend, though the only instructions I can find are a year out of date.  In any case, we are a linux house and do not have AD internally.

Possibly I need an older version of AAD Connect (1.1.649?) but am unable to find this anywhere.

Does anyone have any instructions on how we can configure AAD Connect to work with anything but a local Active Directory?

I have seen this blog posting, but it does not match the current AD Connect software. https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/11/03/generic-ldap-connector-for-azure-ad-connect/

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to doing this.

- Install local Active Directory
- Install AADConnect linking to local AD and Azure AD
- When install has completed, run the ADConnect Synchronisation Service (UIShell) configuration app
- This then allows you to define an LDAP connector, and remove the unnecessary local AD one
- Now you need to define rules using the Synchronisation Rules Editor to trigger updates, creates or deletes
- Now you need to set up profiles in the Synchronisation Service for Full Import and for Sync on each source.

This is not trivial but there is more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/reference/microsoft-identity-manager-2016-connector-genericldap

Don't run the install wizard as it only allows you to configure replication to a local AD, which is pointless as you can set up federation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, now available, is to install the AAD Domain Services object in Azure.  This is, in effect, AD+ADConnect in a managed box, and will give you an LDAP endpoint to AD.  You can then use LDAP replication of some sort to synchronise this with your local LDAP, or else use it directly for authnz.

Drawbacks are that is is, of course AD LDAP and has a strange structure; and the LDAP password synch only happens when the passwords are updated in AAD.  And you cant extend the schema locally.  However it may be enough if authentication and groups are all that is required.

Comment: Another drawback is the expense.  For instance, here in Australia, this equates to an additional AU$150/month - making it too rich a solution for SMB's / mom and pop shops!

Comment: True, AD LDAP is NOT cheap for what it does.